# Bulma/Svelte font-awesome icons not re-rendering

Tags: icons, bulma, font-awesome-5, svelte-3

I have font-awesome icons appearing in a sortable table. They render fine, but when I re-sort the rows of the table, the icons remain where they are, and don't sort (re-render?) with the other table contents. I'm using Svelte3 and Bulma. I'm guessing I need to use Svelte's `bind:this` property, but I'm not certain where, exactly. (The table rows are generated in a Svelte `{#each}` block, FWIW.)

Comment: Would you be able to share some code? how are you rendering the icons, how are you sorting and binding your variables?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: keyed each block**

When you want to reorder an `{#each}` block you need to use a keyed each block:

```
{#each things as thing (thing.id)}
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This would reorder the components and their associated DOM elements.

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks

**Solution 2: reactive declarations**

A key is not always possible. Without a key the first row's internal state wil aways be the state of the first row.

This isn't an issue as long as the internal state is derived/connected to the props.

```
export let thing;
let icon = '/img/icons/' + thing.slug; // wrong
```

This code is run once, the icon is set based on the initial props, but never updated.

```
export let thing;
$: icon = '/img/icons/' + thing.slug; // right
```

Now icon is updated every time a variable on the right side of the `=` change.

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to do something similar here: use FontAwesome with Svelte and have the icons update/re-render on some reactive statement.  After beating our heads against the wall for a long time we discovered we were using Font Awesome JS, which would turn our `<i>` tags into `<svg>`'s.  When we turned off the JS, and only used Font Awesome CSS, the icons would then re-render as desired.